# Facebook like box only working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-likebox

I used the facebook likebox generator to create iframe likebox code.  The following was supplied:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnatrxsa&amp;width=292&amp;height=427&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=true&amp;border_color&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:427px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

However, for some reason it only works in Chrome.

Testing it on local, I changed the `<iframe src="//www.fac` to `<iframe src="http://www.fac` so that it would load in a simple text file.  Tested Opera, Safari, Firefox and IE but only Chrome loads it.

It's probably a silly mistake, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I actually just noticed this issue as well. I'd love to here if anyone's found a rhyme or reason to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to country and age restrictions in the clients Facebook page it would only load the like box when logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved your issue ...but for future referance if anybody else have this problem ... If you are working on a website ... and make a facebook page ... if you don`t have any activity on the facebook page at the beginning, after 2-3 weeks... it will become UNPUBLISHED ... so Firefox, Safari, IE, Opera will not show your Like Box, Like Buttonn or anything else ...so you need to publish your page

PS: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you please share the references for that statement? Thanks.